# Change textfield in movieclip with loop actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, for-loop

I have six movieclips on the stage and I want to build a for loop that will change the text inside of the movieclips. I have an array with all the names in it that i want to be added to each clip.

```
var a_letters:Array = new Array('a','b','c','d','e','f');

for(var i = 0; i <= 6; i++ ){
    var tempBTN = 'btn'+i+'_mc';
    this.getChildByName(tempBTN).letter_txt.html = a_letters[i-1];
}
```

When I run this I get this error

Scene 1, Layer 'ACTIONS', Frame 1, Line 28
1119: Access of possibly undefined property letter_txt through a reference with static type flash.display:DisplayObject.

Comment: `getChildByName` returns a display object. Display objects are not dynamic so they do not have the property "letter_txt". Try casting that to a MovieClip like so:

`MovieClip(this.getChildByName(tempBTN)).letter_txt.html =`

Comment: I think it's better you create an Array and add text fields to this array as objects and reach them with using "for each"

Comment: You can close the question if you've got the right answer, so it won't stay opened and unanswered :)